# Elasticsearch: How to know HTTP port number used when default 9200 is already in use

Tags: elasticsearch

In the Elasticsearch documentation is specified the following regarding to the http.port configuration:

> http.port
>
> Port to bind to for incoming HTTP requests. Accepts a single value or a range. If a range is specified, the node will bind to the first available port in the range.
>
> Defaults to 9200-9300.

Let's say that Elasticsearch automatically selects the port 9202 because the 9200 is already in use. How does a Java client application know which port was selected and has to be used to create a RestHighLevelClient object? Is there a way to query a another service that could provide the port number information?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**

After the first answer I've tried to reproduce the steps in a Windows machine (production environment) by executing the following:

```
> tasklist | findstr "elasticsearch"
elasticsearch-service-x64     2232 Services                   0    537,764 K

> netstat -aon | find /i "2232"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9200           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2232
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9300           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2232
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9200         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2232
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9300         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2232
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49201        127.0.0.1:49202        ESTABLISHED     2232
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49202        127.0.0.1:49201        ESTABLISHED     2232
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49203        127.0.0.1:49204        ESTABLISHED     2232
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49204        127.0.0.1:49203        ESTABLISHED     2232
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49205        127.0.0.1:49206        ESTABLISHED     2232
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49206        127.0.0.1:49205        ESTABLISHED     2232
  ...
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49275        127.0.0.1:49276        ESTABLISHED     2232
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49276        127.0.0.1:49275        ESTABLISHED     2232
  TCP    [::1]:9200             [::]:0                 LISTENING       2232
  TCP    [::1]:9300             [::]:0                 LISTENING       2232
```

The result shows several lines where the 9200 port (http.port) is used:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:9200           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2232
TCP    127.0.0.1:9200         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2232
TCP    [::1]:9200             [::]:0                 LISTENING       2232
```

If I had to parse that result to get the port number, which of those IP addresses should I look for? or simply does not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RestHighLevelClient` is thread-safe and it's instantiated by the application at startup time or when the first request is executed. How is it being done "under the hood" maybe you can check in `RestClientBuilder.java` [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder.java).

Not sure about the question, but if you are not sure which port `ES` is using you can check it

```
[root@myserver ~]# service elasticsearch status
elasticsearch (pid  5384) is running...

## netstat on pid
[root@myserver~]# netstat -plunt | grep 5384
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.100.14.146:9300   :::*                        LISTEN      5384/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.100.14.19:9200    :::*                        LISTEN      5384/java
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:127.0.0.1:9200       :::*                        LISTEN      5384/java
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for a mechanism on the Elasticsearch's Java API (or somewhere else) to somehow find the port of the current installation. My second option was to do something similar as what you proposed, to look on the operating system for the port used by ES. I've edited the answer explaining it :)